# Select Query of third table

Tags: sql, join, firebird

I have these three tables, and each contract can have several units bound to it.
What I need is the sum the field "area" of all units that are in the same contract.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

The query should look like this. The last field "Price fraction" is going to be a calculated field, so I don't need it in the SQL query.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

I've tried writing the query, but it always gives the wrong sum.

```
Select
Unit.description "Unit",
Unit.area "Area",
Contract.price "Contract Value",
(select sum(Unit.area) from Unit, ContractUnit where ContractUnit.unit_id = Unit.id) "area_sum"
from
Unit
JOIN ContractUnit ON ContractUnit.id_unit = Unit.id
JOIN Contract ON Contract.id = ContractUnit.contract_id
where Unit.id = :idUnit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's dissect the requirement and break it up into steps.

**Evaluation**:

There are  three tables:

Unit

Contract

ContractUnit

**Unit** and **Contract** entities have many-to-many relationship and hence there is the need of **ContractUnit** which is the associative entity (or bridge table).

**Step 1**: The following columns first needs listed:
Unit_id , Area (from table **Unit**)

Contract_value(dollars) and contract_id (from table **contract**)

Actually , the final output will not need contract_id but it is still needed in the first step because sum_area is calculated over it. In the final output , we will not display it.

So we get it here:

```
SELECT u.id    unit,
       u.area  area,
       c.price contract_value,
       c.id    contract_id
FROM   unit u
       INNER JOIN contractunit cu
               ON u.id = cu.unit_id
       INNER JOIN contract c
               ON c.id = cu.contract_id
```

Output:

```
 unit | area | contract_value | contract_id
------+------+----------------+-------------
    1 |  340 |         400000 |           1
    2 |  540 |         400000 |           1
    3 |  130 |         560000 |           2
    4 |  503 |         560000 |           2
(4 rows)
```

**Step 2** : we get the final value by doing a sum of area over contract_id on the output obtained above.

```
SELECT unit,
       area,
       subq.contract_value,
       Sum(area)
         OVER (
           partition BY contract_id) sum_area
FROM   (<earlier query> ) subq;
```

that is:

```
SELECT unit,
       area,
       subq.contract_value,
       Sum(area)
         OVER (
           partition BY contract_id) sum_area
FROM   (SELECT u.id    unit,
       u.area  area,
       c.price contract_value,
       c.id    contract_id
FROM   unit u
       INNER JOIN contractunit cu
               ON u.id = cu.unit_id
       INNER JOIN contract c
               ON c.id = cu.contract_id ) subq;
```

Result:

```
unit | area | contract_value | sum_area
------+------+----------------+----------
    1 |  340 |         400000 |      880
    2 |  540 |         400000 |      880
    3 |  130 |         560000 |      633
    4 |  503 |         560000 |      633
(4 rows)
```

--- In case your RDBMS type/version **do not** support window function or even CTE , you can get the same result with this query ---

```
SELECT b.unit,
       b.area,
       b.contract_value,
       a.sum_area
FROM   (SELECT contract_id,
               Sum(area) sum_area
        FROM   (SELECT u.id    unit,
                       u.area  area,
                       c.price contract_value,
                       c.id    contract_id
                FROM   unit u
                       INNER JOIN contractunit cu
                               ON u.id = cu.unit_id
                       INNER JOIN contract c
                               ON c.id = cu.contract_id) subq
        GROUP  BY contract_id) a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT u.id    unit,
                          u.area  area,
                          c.price contract_value,
                          c.id    contract_id
                   FROM   unit u
                          INNER JOIN contractunit cu
                                  ON u.id = cu.unit_id
                          INNER JOIN contract c
                                  ON c.id = cu.contract_id) b
               ON a.contract_id = b.contract_id;
```